# Identify images with white background from webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to loop through images displayed on a webpage to determine which of them have the topmost left pixel white.

```
     $('img').each(function(){

        // create an image object using the current image SRC
        var image = new Image();
        image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        image.src = $(this).attr('src');

        //create a canvas and place the image inside the canvas element
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

        //grab pixel data
        var pixel = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
        $(this).attr('data-pixel', pixel);

        //remove canvas
        $('canvas').remove();

    });
```

Problem is that this now working all the time. When I run it on a single image it works most of the time. But when I go through all the images i get the `data-pixel="0,0,0,0"></img>`.

Am I missing something?I have never tried using this method before. If you know of a different version please let me know.

Comment: 1) Are you sure all of the external images are being sent with the proper CORS header? 2) `getImageData().data` always returns an array (of r,g,b,a values). So you are assigning an array to the `data-pixel` attribute. Are you sure about that?

Comment: Yes, you are missing a few things : as devnull69 correctly stated, if your images are not served with the proper CORS header, the image won't load. But you would probably have noticed it if you fixed the #1 issue : loading an image is asynchronous, even if cached, from a dataURI, from anywhere, it's always async. So by the time you call `drawImage`, the image is not loaded yet, and nothing is drawn on your canvas (`0,0,0,0` is a transparent pixel, not a white one `[255, 255, 255, 255]`). And of course, everything else will need to be called only when the image will have loaded.

Comment: Images are loaded at the point I run it. I loaded it through the console and i get hit and miss. Sometimes it gives me correct values, other times it simply adds 0,0,0,0 to all. This is my problem.

Comment: Strange thing is. I run it once, nothing happens (0,0,0,0), I run it a second time still nothing. 3rd time works perfectly. It's strange.

Comment: No in your code `image` is not yet loaded, even if the media has already been dowloaded, that doesn't change the fact that loading an image (`image.src = something`) is always async.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above I changed the code to trigger the canvas creation and image draw onload like so:

```
    $('img').each(function() {

  var $that = $(this);
  var image = new Image();
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');   
  var imageSource = $that.attr('src');
  image.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  image.src = imageSource;
  image.onload = function() {

      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      //grab pixel data
      var pixel = canvas.getContext('2d').getImageData(0, 0, 1, 1).data;
      $that.attr('data-pixel', pixel.toString());

      if (parseInt(pixel[0]) > 250 && parseInt(pixel[1]) > 250 && parseInt(pixel[2]) > 250) {

          $that.addClass( 'white' );
          $that.closest('table').prepend('<h5>White Background</h5>');

      }
      //remove canvas
      console.log(pixel.toString());
      $('canvas').remove();

  };
```

});